# Keypressed function entered but not functioning correctly

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to assign key listeners to buttons created in a for loop. For some reason, I cannot get the buttons to change background color on keypress. The `System.out.println("passed");` line is being reached, so Im not sure what's going on.

Lots of spaghetti code.. please let me know what else I should add.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ButtonInPane extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
 // input
 String input;
 //context
 JLabel context1, context2;
 // default color
 Color defaultColor = new JButton().getBackground();
 public void addNotify() {
  super.addNotify();
  requestFocus();
 }
 // main rows of keys
 public String rowOne[] = {
  "~",
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "0",
  "-",
  "+",
  "h"
 };
 public String rowTwo[] = {
  "Tab",
  "Q",
  "W",
  "E",
  "R",
  "T",
  "Y",
  "U",
  "I",
  "O",
  "P",
  "[",
  "]",
  "\\"
 };
 public String rowThree[] = {
  "Caps",
  "A",
  "S",
  "D",
  "F",
  "G",
  "H",
  "J",
  "K",
  "L",
  ":",
  "'",
  "Enter"
 };
 public String rowFour[] = {
  "Shift",
  "Z",
  "X",
  "C",
  "V",
  "B",
  "N",
  "M",
  ",",
  ".",
  "?",
  "   ^"
 };
 public String rowFive[] = {
  "       ",
  "<",
  "v",
  ">"
 };
 /**
  * Account for chars with no shift: Program toggles Shift key, meaning if a
  * user clicks on it, all keys will be toggled to their respective shift
  * value. The user can tap the shift key again to change back to regular
  * value
  */
 public String shiftless[] = {
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "0",
  "-",
  "=",
  "q",
  "w",
  "e",
  "r",
  "t",
  "y",
  "u",
  "i",
  "o",
  "p",
  "[",
  "]",
  "\\",
  "a",
  "s",
  "d",
  "f",
  "g",
  "h",
  "j",
  "k",
  "l",
  ";",
  "z",
  "x",
  "c",
  "v",
  "b",
  "n",
  "m",
  ",",
  ".",
  "/"
 };
 // Account for special chars
 public String specialChars[] = {
  "~",
  "-",
  "+",
  "[",
  "]",
  "\\",
  ";",
  ".",
  "?"
 };

 // declare rows of buttons
 public JButton buttons_rowOne[], buttons_rowTwo[], buttons_rowThree[], buttons_rowFour[], buttons_rowFive[];
 private JTextArea body;
 private JPanel top;
 private JPanel middle;
 private JPanel bottom;
 private JPanel contextBox;

 // ctor
 public ButtonInPane() {
  super("Typing Tutor");
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setResizable(false);
  this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
  this.setLocation(50, 50);
  this.setVisible(true);
  __init__();
 }

 public void __init__layout(JPanel top, JPanel middle, JPanel bottom, JPanel contextBox) {
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(contextBox);
  add(middle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }

 public void __init__body() {
  body = new JTextArea();
  body.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 150));
  body.addKeyListener(this);
 }

 public void __init__panels() {
  context1 = new JLabel("Type some text using your keyboard. " +
   "The keys you press will be highlighed and the text will be displayed.");
  context2 = new JLabel("\nNote: Clicking the buttons with your mouse will not perform any action.");
  context1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  context2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  top = new JPanel();
  top.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
  middle = new JPanel();
  bottom = new JPanel();
  contextBox = new JPanel();
  __init__layout(top, middle, bottom, contextBox);
  top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
  top.add(context1);
  top.add(context2);
  middle.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  middle.add(body, BorderLayout.WEST);
  middle.add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 }

 public void __init__() {
  // text area
  __init__body();
  // panels for layout
  __init__panels();
  pack();
  // get length of row strings
  int length_rowOne = rowOne.length;
  int length_rowTwo = rowTwo.length;
  int length_rowThree = rowThree.length;
  int length_rowFour = rowFour.length;
  int length_rowFive = rowFive.length;
  // create array for each row of buttons
  buttons_rowOne = new JButton[length_rowOne];
  buttons_rowTwo = new JButton[length_rowTwo];
  buttons_rowThree = new JButton[length_rowThree];
  buttons_rowFour = new JButton[length_rowFour];
  buttons_rowFive = new JButton[length_rowFive];
  // create panel for each row of buttons
  JPanel r1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowOne));
  JPanel r2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowTwo));
  JPanel r3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowThree));
  JPanel r4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFour));
  JPanel r5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFive));
  // draw out the rows of buttons
  draw(r1, length_rowOne, r2, length_rowTwo, r3, length_rowThree, r4, length_rowFour, r5, length_rowFive);

 }

 // draw rows of buttons
 public void draw(JPanel r1, int s1, JPanel r2, int s2, JPanel r3, int s3, JPanel r4, int s4, JPanel r5, int s5) {
  for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowOne[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowOne[i] = currentButton;
   r1.add(buttons_rowOne[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s2; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowTwo[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowTwo[i] = currentButton;
   r2.add(buttons_rowTwo[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s3; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowThree[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowThree[i] = currentButton;
   r3.add(buttons_rowThree[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s4; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFour[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowFour[i] = currentButton;
   r4.add(buttons_rowFour[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s5; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
   // account for space bar
   if (i == 1) {
    currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
    currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 10));
    currentButton.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 100);
    currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
    buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
   } else {
    currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
    buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
   }
   r5.add(buttons_rowFive[i]);
  }
  bottom.add(r1);
  bottom.add(r2);
  bottom.add(r3);
  bottom.add(r4);
  bottom.add(r5);
 } // !draw(...)
 // called when a button is pressed

 @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent press) {
  Object current = press.getKeyChar();
  System.out.println("passed");
  for (int i = 0; i < rowOne.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
    buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rowTwo.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
    buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rowThree.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowThree[i]) {
    buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rowFour.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowFour[i]) {
    buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rowFive.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowFive[i]) {
    buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  repaint();
 } // !keyPressed(...)
 // called when a button is released

 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent release) {
  Object current = release.getSource();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
    buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
    buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowThree[i]) {
    buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowFour[i]) {
    buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowFive[i]) {
    buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   }
  }
  repaint();
 } // !keyReleased(...)

 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent typed) {
  // Object current = typed.getSource().toString();
  // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  // for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  //   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowThree[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowFour[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowFive[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   }
  // }      
 }
 // main method
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new ButtonInPane();
 } // !main method

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 999;
} // !main class
```

---

Edit 1:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ButtonInPane extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
 // input
 String input;
 //context
 JLabel context1, context2;
 // default color
 Color defaultColor = new JButton().getBackground();
 public void addNotify() {
  super.addNotify();
  requestFocus();
 }
 // main rows of keys
 public char rowOne[] = {
  '~',
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '0',
  '-',
  '+',
  'h'
 };
 public char rowTwo[] = {
  //'Tab', TODO: Make these separate objects
  'Q',
  'W',
  'E',
  'R',
  'T',
  'Y',
  'U',
  'I',
  'O',
  'P',
  '[',
  ']',
  '\\'
 };
 public char rowThree[] = {
  //'Caps',
  'A',
  'S',
  'D',
  'F',
  'G',
  'H',
  'J',
  'K',
  'L',
  ':',
  '"',
  //'Enter'
 };
 public char rowFour[] = {
  //'Shift',
  'Z',
  'X',
  'C',
  'V',
  'B',
  'N',
  'M',
  ',',
  '.',
  '?',
  //'   ^'
 };
 public char rowFive[] = {
  //'       ',
  '<',
  'v',
  '>'
 };
 /**
  * Account for chars with no shift: Program toggles Shift key, meaning if a
  * user clicks on it, all keys will be toggled to their respective shift
  * value. The user can tap the shift key again to change back to regular
  * value
  */
 public char shiftless[] = {
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '0',
  '-',
  '=',
  'q',
  'w',
  'e',
  'r',
  't',
  'y',
  'u',
  'i',
  'o',
  'p',
  '[',
  ']',
  '\\',
  'a',
  's',
  'd',
  'f',
  'g',
  'h',
  'j',
  'k',
  'l',
  ';',
  'z',
  'x',
  'c',
  'v',
  'b',
  'n',
  'm',
  ',',
  '.',
  '/'
 };
 // Account for special chars
 public char specialChars[] = {
  '~',
  '-',
  '+',
  '[',
  ']',
  '\\',
  ';',
  '.',
  '?'
 };

 // declare rows of buttons
 public JButton buttons_rowOne[], buttons_rowTwo[], buttons_rowThree[], buttons_rowFour[], buttons_rowFive[];
 private JTextArea body;
 private JPanel top;
 private JPanel middle;
 private JPanel bottom;
 private JPanel contextBox;

 // ctor
 public ButtonInPane() {
  super("Typing Tutor");
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setResizable(false);
  this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
  this.setLocation(50, 50);
  this.setVisible(true);
  __init__();
 }

 public void __init__layout(JPanel top, JPanel middle, JPanel bottom, JPanel contextBox) {
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(contextBox);
  add(middle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }

 public void __init__body() {
  body = new JTextArea();
  body.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 150));
  body.addKeyListener(this);
 }

 public void __init__panels() {
  context1 = new JLabel("Type some text using your keyboard. " +
   "The keys you press will be highlighed and the text will be displayed.");
  context2 = new JLabel("\nNote: Clicking the buttons with your mouse will not perform any action.");
  context1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  context2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  top = new JPanel();
  top.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
  middle = new JPanel();
  bottom = new JPanel();
  contextBox = new JPanel();
  __init__layout(top, middle, bottom, contextBox);
  top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
  top.add(context1);
  top.add(context2);
  middle.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  middle.add(body, BorderLayout.WEST);
  middle.add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 }

 public void __init__() {
  // text area
  __init__body();
  // panels for layout
  __init__panels();
  pack();
  // get length of row strings
  int length_rowOne = rowOne.length;
  int length_rowTwo = rowTwo.length;
  int length_rowThree = rowThree.length;
  int length_rowFour = rowFour.length;
  int length_rowFive = rowFive.length;
  // create array for each row of buttons
  buttons_rowOne = new JButton[length_rowOne];
  buttons_rowTwo = new JButton[length_rowTwo];
  buttons_rowThree = new JButton[length_rowThree];
  buttons_rowFour = new JButton[length_rowFour];
  buttons_rowFive = new JButton[length_rowFive];
  // create panel for each row of buttons
  JPanel r1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowOne));
  JPanel r2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowTwo));
  JPanel r3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowThree));
  JPanel r4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFour));
  JPanel r5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFive));
  // draw out the rows of buttons
  draw(r1, length_rowOne, r2, length_rowTwo, r3, length_rowThree, r4, length_rowFour, r5, length_rowFive);

 }

 // draw rows of buttons
 public void draw(JPanel r1, int s1, JPanel r2, int s2, JPanel r3, int s3, JPanel r4, int s4, JPanel r5, int s5) {
  for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowOne[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowOne[i] = currentButton;
   r1.add(buttons_rowOne[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s2; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowTwo[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowTwo[i] = currentButton;
   r2.add(buttons_rowTwo[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s3; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowThree[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowThree[i] = currentButton;
   r3.add(buttons_rowThree[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s4; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFour[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
   buttons_rowFour[i] = currentButton;
   r4.add(buttons_rowFour[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s5; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
   // account for space bar
   if (i == 1) {
    currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
    currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 10));
    currentButton.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 100);
    currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
    buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
   } else {
    currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    currentButton.addKeyListener(this);
    buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
   }
   r5.add(buttons_rowFive[i]);
  }
  bottom.add(r1);
  bottom.add(r2);
  bottom.add(r3);
  bottom.add(r4);
  bottom.add(r5);
 } // !draw(...)
 // called when a button is pressed

 @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent press) {
  char current = press.getKeyChar();
  System.out.println("passed");
  for (int i = 0; i < rowOne.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
    buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  // System.out.println(s1 == s2);
  // System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
  for (int i = 0; i < rowTwo.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
    buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rowThree.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowThree[i]) {
    buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rowFour.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowFour[i]) {
    buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rowFive.length; i++) {
   if (current == rowFive[i]) {
    buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   }
  }
  repaint();
 } // !keyPressed(...)
 // called when a button is released

 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent release) {
  char current = release.getSource();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
    buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
    buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowThree[i]) {
    buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowFour[i]) {
    buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   } else if (current == rowFive[i]) {
    buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
   }
  }
  repaint();
 } // !keyReleased(...)

 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent typed) {
  // Object current = typed.getSource().toString();
  // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  // for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  //   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowThree[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowFour[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowFive[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   }
  // }      
 }
 // main method
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new ButtonInPane();
 } // !main method

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 999;
} // !main class
```

Comment: I can't provide an answer, but I did notice that you define "current" as an Object. getKeyChar() returns a char, which is boxed as a Char. This isn't good practice. Try changing it to char and see if your IDE lights up. Your arrays seem to be of type JButton.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fundamental issue with your logic is that the if-statements in `keyPressed` are never true, which is why the print statement is working but not the background color changes. The reason why an if-statement such as `if (current == rowOne[i])` would never be true is that the type of `current` is `Object`, but you're assigning to it `press.getKeyChar()`, which is of type `char`. I'm guessing that this results in [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), meaning that the `char` value then becomes a `Character` object. As for `rowOne[i]`, since the values in `rowOne` are all of type `String`, these are - like for `current` - always objects and not primitives. Directly comparing objects with `==` only determines if the objects *are the same object*, meaning that you are comparing the references and not the value. To compare objects, you need to use `a.equals(b)` to correctly compare the values of the objects (see ["Difference between == and .equals() method in Java"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/)).

In your case, both of these issues combined are causing the if-statement not to work as expected. I would recommend declaring `current` as a `char`, and making your arrays contains `char` primitives rather than `String` objects (e.g. `'A'` rather than `"A"`). In this case, you can directly compare two `char` primitives using `==` and that would at least solve that problem.

Hope this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm getting the error `no suitable constructor found for JButton(char)`. I've updated my code.

Comment: For `char current = release.getSource();` it says the same thing, `Object cannot be converted to char`. I think that this is just an infeasible way to do this, perhaps I should look into a better way altogether?

Comment: @legoMyEgo this is because the constructor is still `JButton(String)`, so you'll need to convert your `char` to a `String`. This can be done in multiple ways, such as `Character.toString(char)` or `String.valueOf(char)`. For your second comment, you need to do the same thing as you did in the `keyPressed(KeyEvent)` method: `char current = release.getKeyChar()`. This is because `KeyEvent#getKeyChar` returns a `char`, and `KeyEvent#getSource` returns an `Object`